# Android : how to deal with relative layout

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-relativelayout

i am stuck from two days with relative layout..here is my screen snap in linear layout[image]

so its fine. but now i want to add refresh button somewhere on map but i found that it is not possible with linear layout. so i tried in relative layout but cant even get screen as above.
my footer layout is always shown at top.. here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- include title bar for all screen -->

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/titlebar_layout" />


<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.63"
    android:apiKey="0VkXbAOFvAq7b6uaGHSmnS2a2VosPxoS6ceHY_g"
    android:clickable="true" >
</com.google.android.maps.MapView>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    layout="@layout/bottom_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: where do you want to put the refresh button??

Comment: thanks for reply..i want to put it at top right corner of mapview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use a frame layout and put the mapview and button inside the frame layout. Thus button will be placed above the mapview. Place it according to your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- include title bar for all screen -->

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/titlebar_layout" />


<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_width="1.0" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.63"
        android:apiKey="0VkXbAOFvAq7b6uaGHSmnS2a2VosPxoS6ceHY_g"
       android:clickable="true" >
   </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

   <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</FrameLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    layout="@layout/bottom_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps...!!!

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout is probably what you want. It can be difficult to program, as you need to define the bottom View *first*, and then the Views which come above it on the screen.

Check out [these](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-relative-layouts/) [tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/) for some more assistance on using RelativeLayouts. The best way to learn is by doing it! Experiment with various layouts until you figure out how the rules work. Then it should be pretty simple to recreate this as a RelativeLayout.

Comment: thanks buddy for your suggestion..i will try from scratch..thanks again